# how can I solve a issue with andWhere with symfony/doctrine and odbc?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

While following the symfony tutorial (1.4.4) I'm getting an error with ODBC/mssql 2008.

> SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
>   (SQLExecute[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254). Failing Query:
>   "SELECT [j].[id] AS [j__id], [j].[category_id] AS [j__category_id],
>   [j].[type] AS [j__type], [j].[company] AS [j__company], [j].[logo] AS
>   [j__logo], [j].[url] AS [j__url], [j].[position] AS [j__position],
>   [j].[location] AS [j__location], [j].[description] AS
>   [j__description], [j].[how_to_apply] AS [j__how_to_apply], [j].[token]
>   AS [j__token], [j].[is_public] AS [j__is_public], [j].[is_activated]
>   AS [j__is_activated], [j].[email] AS [j__email], [j].[expires_at] AS
>   [j__expires_at], [j].[created_at] AS [j__created_at], [j].[updated_at]
>   AS [j__updated_at] FROM [jobeet_job] [j] WHERE ([j].[category_id] =
>   '2' AND [j].[expires_at] > ?) ORDER BY [j].[expires_at] DESC"

I've narrowed the problem to a line that uses parameters

`public function getActiveJobs(Doctrine_Query $q = null)
    {
        if (is_null($q))
        {
            $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
              ->from('JobeetJob j');
        }`

```
    //$q->andWhere('j.expires_at > \''.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).'\'');<-- this works
    $q->andWhere('j.expires_at > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())); //<-- this line has problem
    $q->addOrderBy('j.expires_at DESC');

    return $q->execute();
}
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it work when you enclose the `date()` function in the second like with apostrophes like in the first line?

Comment: Yeah, It works like that, but it won't sanitize the database input

Answer (score 0):

I "solved it" changing to

$q->andWhere('j.expires_at >=?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s' time()));

Its a temporary solution, and it works for, now, but i'd like to know why it doesn't works with only the >.
Thanks

Comment: If it's of any interest, I'm able to use the following without problems (MySQL): $q->andWhere('date_created > ?', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('30 days ago'))); Strange problem.